# Leaflet - toggling GeoJSON layers without plug-ins

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

I know how to add a layer with markers, which I can toggle on/off and how to add `GeoJSON` layer to my map.

But I can't mix these functions.

I need to create a `toggling layer from GeoJSON` (polyline layer).

Is it possible to get what I need ***without any external plug-ins or scripts***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoJSON Layers and Markers can be used together without problem.

To be able to toggle your layers, you need to catch some sort of click event from something you can click on, for example a button.
From my research what I found is if you need a custom button, it is not so quick to implement yourself, so you might need to use one of the available plugins.

If you still do not want to build a button or use a plugin, you could for example set a click event on the map itself, which toggles the GeoJSON layer on and off.

I took the GeoJSON example from the leaflet website and changed it so it toggles the GeoJSON layer on and off:

```
var geoLayer = L.geoJson([
  // ...
]);

map.on('click', function() {
  if(map.hasLayer(geoLayer)) {
    map.removeLayer(geoLayer);
  } else {
    map.addLayer(geoLayer);
  }
});
```

Hope that helps..

**Edit:**
I changed the example to use the layer control of leaflet.js
which is much better...

```
var baseLayers = {
  "Markers": markerLayer,
  "GeoJSON": geoLayer
};
L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

Didn't know about this ;)

If you want **checkboxes** instead of radiobuttons, use this instead

```
L.control.layers(null, baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEaEBg

Comment: If you have an idea, how to get what I need with plugins, please tell me. :) I need to solve it quickly.

Comment: It works! :) Two minor questions left. How to move this layer control panel to the left side? And how to set this layer control panel to be visible all the time, not hidden, when I move the cursor away from the icon?

Comment: You can position it like this:
 L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map).setPosition('bottomright');
There are all sorts of things you can do, just read the documentation.. http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-options

Comment: Damn, can't stop thinking about a problem if you ask me for it.. there is a 'collapsed' option which you can easily turn off like this:
L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, {collapsed: false}).setPosition ('topleft').addTo(map);
I updated the codepen example above accordingly